# xfce-session without panels on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, xfce

My cygwin workflow is as follows

1. Run XServer
2. Start xfce session (by running xfce4-session)
3. Start xfce4-terminal

Everything works well, except that xfce4-session seems to bring up an empty floating-panel, which I'm unable to hide without killing the session itself. Is there a way to configure xfce so this panel doesn't get shown?

PS: Running xfce4-terminal by itself gives me the terminal emulator, but the terminal behaves nicer when xfce4-session is active--text is anti-aliased, icons are slicker, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try killing just the panel process itself:

```
killall xfce4-panel
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the right way to start xfce is running /usr/bin/startxfce4. 
If you want to run it the way you are, perhaps you could right click on the panel and click remove to get rid of it. 
xfwm4 is the Window Manager, xfce-session is the session manager which "Restores your session on startup and allows you to shutdown the computer from Xfce."

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that running `xfsettingsd` will load the XFCE theme and settings.

Using that command you can initiate the XFCE configuration without running the full desktop environment.

`xfsettingsd &; xfce4-terminal;`